# Changes Not Taking Effect on Live Website

Tags: ftp, ftp-client

I am currently facing a critical issue with my website hosted on the WinHost platform. I have made changes to the code of the server and restarted the application pool after uploading the updated files. However, despite these efforts, the changes are not reflecting on the live website.

Here's what I've done so far:

1. Made necessary changes to the code on the server.
2. Uploaded the updated files to the server.
3. Restarted the application pool.

Despite these actions, the modifications I made are not visible on the live website. I have also cleared my browser's cache and tried accessing the site from different browsers, but the issue persists.

Any one can please provide guidance on potential solutions?

Thank you.

I expected that after making these changes and restarting the application pool, the modifications would be visible on the live website. However, despite these efforts, the changes are not reflecting as expected.